# Cannot assign value of type 'Data?' to type 'Data?'

Tags: swift

I have an API Call function that I have been using in few projects.

This error occurred in a new project that I created after adding the usual API call function.

This should work even the error message doesn't make sense:

[image]

```
static func callPost(url:String, params:[String:Any], finish: @escaping ((message:String, data:Data?)) -> Void)
{
    let theUrl = URL(string: url)!

    var request = URLRequest(url: theUrl)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"

    let postString = self.getPostString(params: params)
    request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)

    var result:(message:String, data:Data?) = (message: "Fail", data: nil)
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in

        if(error != nil)
        {
            result.message = "Fail Error not null : \(error.debugDescription)"
        }
        else
        {
            result.message = "Success"
            result.data = data
        }

        finish(result)
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Notes:

- I have checked the old project (from which I have copied this code) and it still runs and builds just fine.
- I am using Xcode 9.3.1 and Swift 4.1

Comment: Can you please post your code as text?

Comment: Do you really need to use a tuple here?

Comment: Your code compiles without problems in Xcode 9.4.1 (Swift 4.1)

Comment: @idmean I have added the code as text

Comment: it depends on the returned data @Scriptable

Comment: @martin R thanks for the info I will try updating Xcode

Comment: You want to produce message and data in your closure function.  And why are you setting data to a variable within itself?

Comment: I really think this error is because of some other error. You should try this method in some other clean project. OR may be you can comment this line to see the actual error.

Comment: @Desdenova thanks for the advice but it didn't work

Comment: Thanks @Karman , I have already tried that it works just fine when i comment the line

Comment: @MartinR Lol look at the highlighting, he has defined `Data` as his own class somewhere.

Comment: @OscarApeland: Good catch – but that's a typical problem which can be solved by creating a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the highlighting, the `Data` type you're attempting to write to is defined by you, and is not the same `Data` type from Foundation that `URLRequest` returns. You need to remove your own `Data` type and use Foundation's `Data` instead.

Also as a side note, I'm guessing you're comparing "Success" and "Fail" somewhere else, that's kinda a bad practice, this is an ideal use case for enums. Here's a cleaner way to do it:

```
enum NetworkingResult {
    case fail(Error)
    case success(Data)
}

func getNetworkStuff(_ completion: @escaping (NetworkingResult) -> Void) {
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: URL(string: "https://example.com")!) { data, response, error in
        if let error = error {
            completion(.fail(error))
        } else if let data = data {
            completion(.success(data))
        }
    }.resume()
}


getNetworkStuff { result in
    switch result {
    case .fail(let error):
        // Handle error

    case .success(let data):
        // Handle data
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer however i am still having the same type of error but this time: Cannot assign value of type '(message: String, data: Data?)' to type '(message: String, data: Data?)'

Thanks for the advice and code sample it looks cleaner indeed

Comment: @SeifMeddeb I just copied your code and it runs fine in my environment. Try restarting Xcode, your computer, or see if there's errors anywhere else in your program. If there's something else that fails to compile, that might propagate and make it seem like an error elsewhere. But also what you are attempting to do is shitty code, please consider doing what I'm suggesting with enums.

Comment: Oh lol I see your mistake. You've defined `Data` as a class or struct somewhere else yourself, and the compiler is using that class when you define the tuple, and URLSession returns Foundations's Data. You should absolutely not define your own `Data`, CMD+Click on the blue-ish `Data` to see where you defined it, then rename or delete it.

Comment: If you insist on letting this stay (which is BAD), you can fix the error by explicitly using the module namespace and initializing whatever you've defined as `Data` with the `Foundation.Data` returned from the URLRequest

Comment: I agree i will try the code you suggested it looks much cleaner, thanks

Comment: @SeifMeddeb Good! But that still won't work until you fix the ambiguous use of Data problem.

Comment: Thanks @Oscar Apeland you saved me a lot of time